# Is there any way to solve this equation without knowing the inverse modulo?

Tags: finite-fields, cryptography

Suppose I have an arbitrary 256 bit number $m$ another secret number $k$ of the same bit length, and then I multiply them both modulo a 256 bit prime number $p$ to get $c$ as follows:
$$
c = (m\cdot k) \mod p
$$
Is there any way to get $m$ back without knowing $k$?
Is this problem as hard as the discrete log problem?
How can this task be made more computationally difficult?

Comment: Without knowing $k$, $m$ can be literally anything. So discrete log is not going to help you, the problem is simply impossible.

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek supports Monica Can this be used as a good crypto system ?

Comment: It’s just as good and just as bad as any other [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad). (The most common construction uses XOR, which is slightly easier to implement, but mathematically speaking any abelian group will work just the same, such as the one you use.)

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek supports Monica Thankyou very much ! Is this easy for a Quantum computer to break ?

Comment: Neither quantum computers nor any other kind can break a one-time pad.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Can this be used as a good crypto system ?

Comment: This is the wrong site to ask about that, and I am the wrong person.  But it would appear to have all the same advantages and disadvantages as any other one-time pad.  Whether that's "good" depends on your requirements.  It certainly doesn't seem to be any significant improvement on what's well known.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Thankyou very much ! But can you please tell me if a same key **k** is used for different **m** . How can an attacker exploit the key repetition to break this one time pad ? Is there any "mathematical exploit" to this construction ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really interested in discussing this any further.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge Thankyou, your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Since p is prime, each element except 1 has a multiplicative inverse, so k can be anything you want, and $m=c\cdot k^{-1}$ and you can compute $k^{-1}$ with the extended Euclidean algorithm.  Usually you'd use exponentiation by repeated squaring whose inverse is discrete log, or point multiplication on an elliptic curve by repeated doubling, etc.  I downvoted because this is not a research math question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$c$ represents a congruence class, and there are $p$ of them. However both $m$ and $k$ belong to the same [complete residue system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse), and so for any given $c$ there are $2^{256}$ pairs of $m,k$ that satisfy the equation. So, the answer is no.

Comment: Is it wise to use this a good crypto system ?

Comment: That's a good question for https://crypto.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your answer ! How can I move this question to get more answers from there regarding crypto?

Comment: This question isn't very crypto, so belongs here. Ask different questions over at crypto and see what responses you get.

Comment: Thankyou, that's the same reason why I felt it should be posted it here. I am very much happy with your explanation. By the way can you please tell me how you calculated that there are 2 raised to 256 pairs for any given c ?

Comment: By using [complete residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Residue_systems) as developed by Gauss in [Disquisitiones Arithmeticae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disquisitiones_Arithmeticae), which states the number of (non-zero) residues modulo a prime $p$ is $p-1$.

Comment: Do you think this construction is weak like a Affine cipher as pointed out by Nemo in the second answer?

Comment: @jmp $$ _\pi U_n=\bigcup_t \;_\pi U_n(t) $$ First time someone deleted a posting within seconds after I corrected a typesetting issue in it. But for future reference you may want to know that among the advantages of \bigcup over \large\cup are the positions of the subscripts and superscripts, as in $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty, $ etc. (Besides the other advantages.) $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy; I found too many errors in it, so I'm going to look at it over the week, maybe even come up with a fancy name! Thanks for the MathJax tip.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of an affine cipher.  See the Wikipedia article on affine ciphers (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_cipher) for a discussion on weaknesses and cryptanalysis.  It is not considered a good system of encryption.

Comment: I read that page, but I don't think that it will be easy to guess the key here, because of its large bit size. Further more I am thinking that if we use a different **k**, frequency analysis won't be able to crack it. I don't think my question is along the lines of a mono alphabet substitution cipher, where **each** letter is mapped to an element in the field {0, ..., p-1}. Please can you explain a little more, of why you thought my method, is weak like the Affine cipher...